# Node application and insertion in Mongodb timestamp, problem with Date type and locale time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timestamp, format, mqtt

I have a node application that receives data from MQTT, where various parameters and timestamp are sent to the broker. The server and hardware are correctly configured with local time (Spain).

When I am going to do the insertion in the database, in this case MongoDB, I format the timestamp to be able to insert it in the mongo date format.

The problem is that only the javascript Date() can insert the date format in mongo and I always get two hours less than my local time.

```js
//Format timestamp to date with dayjs
let date = dayjs(data.channels.timestamp * 1000).format()
//Output: 2021-09-16T13:32:33+02:00
```

```js
//Format date to insert in MongoDB
  let timestamp_ = new Date(date);
//Output: 2021-09-16T11:32:33.000Z
```

The correct date is: *2021-09-16T13:32:33+02:00*

I tried momentjs and I have the same problem.

Comment: Do you think that the Intl class could help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

This way you won't need a new library and can specify the country too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal to have date in timezone GMT+0. Date object assumes the date is always GMT+0. Keep it like that and store everything in GMT+0.
Manipulate your query according to the time zone, not the data stored.